How to display formGroup when i use formArray
I want my form to have the form group but right now my form group is covered by form array.
Ts file:
donationItemForm = new FormArray<FormGroup<DonationItemForm>>([]);

HTML file:
<form [formGroup]="donationItemForm">

The error is this:
Type FormArray<FormGroup<DonationItemForm>> is not assignable to type FormGroup
Type FormArray<FormGroup<DonationItemForm>> is not assignable to type FormGroup<any>

I have tried using formArrayName but still failed.

From Angular 17 you can iterate direct over formArray controls and NOT use formGroup
@for (group of donationItemForm.controls; track $index) {
  <div [formGroup]="group">
    <input formControlName="prop1"/>
    ...
  </div>
}

stackblitz

Just one minor thing: @for requires a track expression, so this code won't compile. Otherwise, great solution!

thank you. this is the answer im looking for

@JSONDerulo, thanks for the advise, just corrected in the answer
